# how to get a directory path as an input and read a file from that path in java?

Tags: file-io

i want to read files by a directory path string, 
for example i want this method to return the corresponding file:

> File reader(String pathFile){....
>   return File;}

`File reader(String pathFile){
return File;}`

Answer (score 0):

in the reader function :

```
  File f = new     File(directoryPath,filename);
  f.createNewFile(); //to create a new file in the directory.surround with try and catch as it throws IOEXCEPTION

 return f;
```

you can also use f.mkdir() to create new directory if it doesnt exist.